# PDF Reader with word selection

Tags: android, pdf

I am learning a new language and I would like to read a book in my Android phone. I am trying to make a personal app that opens the book .PDF file and when I click a word it searches in a database and gives me the translation. However I am having a hard time being able to open the PDF file and get the word from the click.

I have used this library:
https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library
and have succesfully opened the PDF file. However I don't know where to start in order to get the word text in a click. After I have the word I believe I am able to do the search for the definition. I am however unable to modify the PDF reader in order to capture the word clicked.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in order to achieve this?
It is fine if another library should be used.

Thank you

Comment: Just a note: PDF files typically do not contain "words". They contain a lot of single characters (or more accurately, "glyphs" – the ligature `fi` for example is a single "glyph" but not a single character), which are placed on x/y coordinates. Getting a single word out of any PDF can be pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult task to select a word in pdf. Checkout [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/)